# How to get Unicode from embeded font file in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts

I am trying to get correct unicode for the documents in which CMap is erroneous. Here I am thinking to get unicode from font file. Is there any way to get unicode from font file. I got that 'cmap' of font file will map character code to gid, 'glyf' will map gid to information required to draw the glyph. Is there any such map, so that I can get Unicode from character code?
You Can find the document here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ve1n4yeHzutTspIVwVRu6jT1vY2RQvvs/view?usp=drivesdk .     In the given PDF font G1 has the following cmap

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo 
<<
  /Registry (Adobe)
  /Ordering (UCS)
  /Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000><FFFF>
endcodespacerange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

In the above cmap I can see only code space range. What about code points? How I can get unicode for the CID's?

Comment: What's the platform and encoding identifier of that mentioned cmap of your font? Could you share the PDF in question?

Comment: *"Is there any way to get unicode from font file"* - probably. Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: As far as I can see (looking at the PDF font information and at the font program itself using FontForge), there appears to be no information to allow automatic mapping from G1 glyphs to Unicode in the PDF.